# How to get average of a column in terms of another column?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, crystal-reports

How to get average of a column in terms of another column and put this value in a third column, and this value will be evaluated for each retrieved record?

"How to perform an opertaion on two columns in a report and insert the result in a third column?"

FYI: I'm using CrystalReport Designer embedded with VisualStudio.NET 2005.

Comment: I might be being dumb here, but I don't know what you mean by "the average of a column in terms of another column". Could you expand on that a bit?

Comment: Say, you have a column holds Fare value, and another column holds Commission value, I'd like to insert a new column holds value of average of commission in terms of Fare.

Comment: I feel me dumb too (and english is not my language), but I really cannot understand. What should that "in terms of" mean algorithmically? Some kind of weighted average?

Comment: As I said before, suppose there is a column that holds certain values, let's say, "Fare" value, and another column holds "Commission" value, I'd like to add a third column in the report to holds commission percentage of fare for each record, let's talk about average later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create formula (with content like "{table.commission}/{table.fare}*100"). I hope next MSDN link will help you (I personally have never used embedded variant of CRD):

[Crystal Reports Basic for Visual Studio
Formula Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms225366.aspx)